# ck editor text area send a null value yet there is a text value

Tags: jquery, laravel, ckeditor

i am fetching data from the database and then viewing it ata form where i want to update it.so i want o get the rental details value from the table in the database and view it in the text area input form.also i have integrated ck editor so that the user can make an edit efficiently on the text area.the issue am getting is am able to get the value of the rental details from the table and shows very well in the textarea but when i send the request it shows a null value yet on the text area it shows there is a text.
i have tested another case whereby when i remove the ck editor from the text area the value is sent on post request

[![in the form][1]][1]

The form

upon making a post request

[![when i send a post request][2]][2]

where might I be going wrong?

in the blade file

```
<div class="form-group inputdetails">
      <label>Rental Details<span class="text-danger inputrequired">*</span></label>
       <textarea class="form-control text-white bg-dark rental-details" name="rental_details" placeholder="Describe the Rental property here.explain it with as more details as possible" rows="4">
            </textarea>
   </div>
```

in the script

```
$('.rental-details').ckeditor();
$('.rental_details').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_details);
```

here is my ajax code in the script that sends the data in the form to the controller

$('#edithouse').click(function(){

```
     var url = '{{ route("updaterentaldetails", ":id") }}';
     updatehseurl = url.replace(':id',rentalhsedetailsid);

     var form = $('.updaterentaldetails')[0];
     var formdata=new FormData(form);
     $.ajax({
        url:updatehseurl,
        method:'POST',
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        data:formdata,
        success:function(response)
        {
           console.log(response);
           if (response.status==400)
           {
              $('#update_errorlist').html(" ");
              $('#update_errorlist').removeClass('d-none');
              $.each(response.message,function(key,err_value)
              {
                 $('#update_errorlist').append('<li>' + err_value + '</li>');
              })

           } else if (response.status==200)
           {
                 alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
                 alertify.success(response.message);
                 activerentalhousestable.ajax.reload();
                 $('#editrentalhsedetailsmodal').modal('hide'); 
           }

        }
     });
  })
```

am passing the data current data to amodal using an ajax call

````
   $('body').on('click','.editrentalhsedetails',function(){
        var rentalhsedetailsid=$(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
          url:'{{ url("admin/activerental",'') }}' + '/' + rentalhsedetailsid + '/edit',
        method:'GET',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(response)
        {
           if (response.status==404)
           {
              alert(response.message);
           } 
           else if(response.status==200)
           {
              // console.log(response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_details)
              $('#editrentalhsedetailsmodal').modal('toggle');
              $('#rentalhouseid').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.id);
              $('.edit_title').html('Edit details for Rental house');
              $('#rental_title').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_name);
              $('#rental_slug').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_slug);               $('#monthly_rent').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.monthly_rent);         $('#rentldetails').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_details);
              

              $('#totalrooms').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.total_rooms);
              $('.rentalhseimage').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_image);
              
              $('.rentalhsevideo').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_video);

              $(".rentalselectcat").select2();
              $(".rentalselectcat").val(response.editrentalhsedetail.housecategory.id).trigger('change');

              $(".rentalhsevacancy").select2();
              $(".rentalhsevacancy").val(response.editrentalhsedetail.vacancy_status).trigger('change');

              $(".rentalhselocation").select2();
              $(".rentalhselocation").val(response.editrentalhsedetail.houselocation.id).trigger('change');

              
              var tagsobject = response.editrentalhsedetail.housetags;
              var tagsarray = $.map(tagsobject, function(el) { 
                 return el['id']; 
              });
              //pass array object value to select2
              $(".rentaltagselect2").select2();
              $('.rentaltagselect2').val(tagsarray).trigger('change');

              // preview an image that was previously uploaded
              var showimage=$('#showimage').attr('src', '/imagesforthewebsite/rentalhouses/rentalimages/small/' + response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_image);
              $('.rentalimg').html(showimage);

              $('input[name^="is_featured"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.is_featured+'"').prop('checked', true);

              $('input[name^="waterbill"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.waterbill+'"').prop('checked', true);

              $('input[name^="electricitybill"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.electricitybill+'"').prop('checked', true);

              $('input[name^="wifi"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.wifi+'"').prop('checked', true);

              $('input[name^="generator"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.generator+'"').prop('checked', true);

              $('input[name^="balcony"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.balcony+'"').prop('checked', true);

              $('input[name^="parking"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.parking+'"').prop('checked', true);

              $('input[name^="cctv_cameras"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.cctv_cameras+'"').prop('checked', true);

              $('input[name^="servant_quarters"][value="'+response.editrentalhsedetail.servant_quarters+'"').prop('checked', true);
           }
        }
     })

     //   update rental tags details
     $('#edithouse').click(function(){

        var url = '{{ route("updaterentaldetails", ":id") }}';
        updatehseurl = url.replace(':id',rentalhsedetailsid);

        var form = $('.updaterentaldetails')[0];
        var formdata=new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
           url:updatehseurl,
           method:'POST',
           processData:false,
           contentType:false,
           data:formdata,
           success:function(response)
           {
              console.log(response);
              if (response.status==400)
              {
                 $('#update_errorlist').html(" ");
                 $('#update_errorlist').removeClass('d-none');
                 $.each(response.message,function(key,err_value)
                 {
                    $('#update_errorlist').append('<li>' + err_value + '</li>');
                 })

              } else if (response.status==200)
              {
                    alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-right');
                    alertify.success(response.message);
                    activerentalhousestable.ajax.reload();
                    $('#editrentalhsedetailsmodal').modal('hide'); 
              }

           }
        });
     })
  })```


where might I be missing the point here


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4CyO.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GGZ1.png
````

Comment: It doesn't look you should use `setData` call, have you tried without it?

Comment: try this  <textarea class="form-control text-white bg-dark rental-details" name="rental_details" placeholder="Describe the Rental property here.explain it with as more details as possible" rows="4"></textarea>     remove spaces between <textarea></textarea>

Comment: @Ksi yes i used this way $('.rental_details').val(response.editrentalhsedetail.rental_details); and still it worked but still sends a null request

Comment: @UmerFayyaz i tried that but still i get a null request upon posting yet i have been able to add the  old value  in the textarea

Comment: @stephenWeru there seems to be a lot of code missing in your question. Where does the `response` come from? when do you initiate the editor vs that request etc

Comment: let me add some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add ID to CKeditor textarea for the answer above?

HTML:

```html
    <div class="form-group inputdetails">
      <label>Rental Details<span class="text-danger inputrequired">*</span></label>
       <textarea class="form-control text-white bg-dark rental-details" name="rental_details" id="rental_details" placeholder="Describe the Rental property here.explain it with as more details as possible" rows="4">
            </textarea>
   </div>
```

JS:

```js
<script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#rental_details' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
```

If this doesn't work, can u tell us if u type in the data through editor or just post default value? Cuz maybe ur not setting it right. From the code above we can only see the placeholder, so there is no actual data.

UPDATE:
so if u want to post your old data that is coming from db (what you would want to do for example in edit functionality):

```php
    <textarea class="form-control text-white bg-dark rental-details name="rental_details" id="rental_details">{!! old('rental_details', $oldDataDbQuery->rental_details) !!}</textarea>
```

assuming ur getting object from $oldDataDbQuery object that has property of 'rental_details'
Anyway just pass data u want to be in field by default inside textarea, and be careful to use {!! !!} instead of {{ }}

UPDATE 2: API WAY

Controller:

```php
public function getRentalDetails(Request $request)
    {
        $rentalDetails = Model::where('id', $request->product_id)->find($request->product_id);

            return response()->json($product->rental_details);
    }
```

where Model is your model that holds object that has property rental_details, product_id (just as example) is that object that you're currently working with, u can take it from request if ur passing data from browser with route like {id}. Then u return json response of that string.

web.php:

```php
    Route::match('getRentalDetails', 'Model@getRentalDetails')->name('getRentalDetails');
```

then in your blade file u just make ajax request to that route with product_id that will compare it and find value for specific one.
I know too little info so that i can help u doing this completely but u should understand how it works now.

EDIT 3:
after private discussion i have made u working example of what should u do on page to properly render ck editor field after displaying modal and getting an api response:

```js
let response = {
    key1    : 'val1',
  key2  : 'val2',
  rental_details_ck : '<p><b>data</b></p> from api with rental details of ckeditor', //this is data like ckeditor saves in database, for example
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rental_details_edit").click(function(){
  // here u do ur ajax request, u can return rest of code block on success, make sure to pass in id for ajax call so that u can return relevant data for that record in database.
  //query should look like this - $rental_details_editor = Model::where('id', $id)->first();
  // from controller u can return just object property needed, doesn't have to be whole object.
    $("#rental_details_ck").html('<textarea id="editor">' + response.rental_details_ck + '</textarea>');
        ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/35.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<body>

<button id="rental_details_edit">Edit</button>

<div id="rental_details_ck">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

in order to setup api from index page u must register route in web.php, setup method in controller and return response as json. ajax call should be done in marked place.

Comment: yes i have followed on the link @sheeraz ahmed has added in the answer because am using ck editor and not the classic editor but still i get a null value on post request

Comment: this code adds ckeditor to your textarea. ck editor just formats it as html so your database value will be in html format. If it is not posting your data, then problem is not with the ckeditor, try removing it and post with ordinary textarea. Include more info on how and where from u post data, dd request object before posting it.

Comment: now we are on the same page.i have tried that,i've removed the ck editor and it perefctly sends the value while using the default text area.lets say for example in the edit form i want to change one of the inputs without altering the rental details input text area,on posting the request with the old value i get an empty rental details request but if i make a change on the rental details the request is sent. i want to achieve this if the old value of the rental details isnt changed still the value is sent and not an empty value.. let me add some info in the question.

Comment: okay so if i understand correctly u want to preserve default (or old) data so that it can be posted.

i will update my answer now

Comment: how can i fetch and pass the old value using jquery here because am using am modal to display and update the data?

Comment: for that u will need to create API resource that will fetch data with ajax... i think there is no need for that as it would be the same later, u will be doing same thing... get the data from your controller for the current id, put it inside variable, send variable back to view with compact() and print it out wherever u need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247469/discussion-between-stephen-weru-and-cicovic-dejan).

Comment: thanks alot @cicovic dejan i learn alot from the discussion

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof ClassicEditor !== 'undefined') {
        var editorData
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'bold',
                        'italic'
                    ],
                    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
                }
            }) .then( editor => {
                editorData = editor;
            } )
            .catch(error => {
            });
    }
```

this code is working in my case

Answer (score 0):

Try to this code

```
   <script>
    ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#rental-details' ) )
    .catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
    } );
    </script>
```

Note that, Don’t forget to add the following CDN file to your blade view file in laravel or any project

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/23.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

if want to ckeditor data get into jquery or javascript see the details [click here](https://oursbrand.com/answer/javascript/how-to-cant-access-text-from-ckeditor-javascript)

Comment: it doesnt work..in my case here i am fetching data from the database display it in a text area input which i have integrated ck editor.am able to show the oldvalue in the text area with ckeditor in the edit form but when i make a post request without changing the old value(adding or removing any letter) it sends a null request

Comment: if (typeof ClassicEditor !== 'undefined') {
        var editorData
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading',
                        '|',
                        'bold',
                        'italic'
                    ],
                    shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
                }
            }) .then( editor => {
                editorData = editor;
            } )
            .catch(error => {
            });
    }

Comment: this code is working in my case